# Cannot start Tomcat 7.0 in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7

I cannot start my tomcat 7.0 server instance 
The following is the stacktrace for the error.

```
  Mar 05, 2015 11:38:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_17/bin/../jre/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_17/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_17/bin/../jre/lib/i386;C:\oraclexe11g\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin;C:\eclipse-jee-luna-SR2-win32\eclipse;;.
Mar 05, 2015 11:38:26 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:BEProject' did not find a matching property.
Mar 05, 2015 11:38:26 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 05, 2015 11:38:26 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 05, 2015 11:38:26 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 458 ms
Mar 05, 2015 11:38:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 05, 2015 11:38:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.55
Mar 05, 2015 11:38:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/BEProject]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/BEProject]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [AjaxServlet] and [ajax.example.AjaxExampleServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/someservlet/*] which is not permitted
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2396)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2072)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2033)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2026)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2026)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1291)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:876)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5378)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Mar 05, 2015 11:38:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Mar 05, 2015 11:38:26 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

Mar 05, 2015 11:38:26 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 05, 2015 11:38:26 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 05, 2015 11:38:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Mar 05, 2015 11:38:26 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 05, 2015 11:38:26 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

I tried to change the http ports to unused ones and checked if any instance of other server were running.

Comment: Delete the server from "SERVER" in eclipse you already configured. And configure a new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the url-pattern for all servlet.
The url-pattern must be unique.
It seems your are using same url-pattern (/someservlet/*) for AjaxServlet and ajax.example.AjaxExampleServlet

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [AjaxServlet] and [ajax.example.AjaxExampleServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/someservlet/*] which is not permitted
```

Answer (score 2):

I think if you look closely at your stack trace, you'll see that the problem is clearly spelled out:

> The servlets named [AjaxServlet] and [ajax.example.AjaxExampleServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/someservlet/*] which is not permitted
>       at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:293)

Try changing the `url-pattern` of either `AjaxServlet` or `ajax.example.AjaxExampleServlet` from `/someservlet/*` to something else.